# How draw bounding box on Specfic Area using Opencv python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to know how to draw a bounding box on a specific area as shown in the picture below using OpenCV python?

[image]

[image: the picture is attached below]

Comment: Threshold to find the darkest area. The clean with morphology. Then get contours.  Then get the bounding box.

Comment: I am new to python, I am stuck in this Can you please share the cide

Comment: Post an original image without the blue rectangle.

Comment: I have posted original Image please check

Comment: I tried it. But the dark regions on the left and right confuse the process and I could not distinguish only the center region. Sorry.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Python/OpenCV code. I can get the region by a judicious choice of area thresholding. But this is not likely going to be robust for other images.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("younas.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# median filter
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 9)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert
thresh_inv = 255 - thresh

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_inv , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# filter on area and draw rectangle biased to compensate for median blur
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 1000 and area < 3000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
        cv2.rectangle(result, (x-9, y-9), (x+w+9, y+h+9), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("younas_threshold.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("younas_result.jpg", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Bounding box:

[image]

Comment: How do you set the area (1000,3000)?

Comment: I did a quick measurement of the dimensions (manually).  That is why I said I did not think the solution was going to be robust.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work well, so How to make it robust/?

Comment: I do not know any robust way. I did not want to post because it was not robust. But you insisted that you needed me to show you what I did.

Comment: `@ Hammad Younas` Since I went to the trouble to post the code as you requested, it would be nice of you to give my answer at least a simple up-vote.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, definitely i will give up-vote